# MySQL Creates Lowercase tables

Tags: mysql

So I create a table in navicat, it creates the table as lowercase
 i.e
Address result is address
then in the ini file I added 
"lower_case_table_names=0" after searching on google, it fixed it but now I have a Script with a bunch of tables and references, here is one table

```
CREATE TABLE `Address`
(
ID INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(ID)
)ENGINE=InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf32 COLLATE=utf32_general_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

Now I have the same result "lowercase table"

Comment: what os is your mysql server running on?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [case sensitivity docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)

> Mode 2 allows to store tables with specified lettercase

and try

```
lower_case_table_names=2 --if you are not on linux
```

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: did you restart the server after setting this?

Comment: yeah, I restarted the service, then restarted the server aswell